# Preventing SIGQUIT from terminating interactive python

Tags: python, signals, ipython, coredump

The keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> causes python and ipython to core dump and quit immediately.  How can I prevent this?  I don't want to disable the key or remap the keyboard.

I have recently moved to a UK keyboard and the backslash/pipe key, which I'm used to having above the Enter key, is now located in between the left shift and the Z key.  I find I'm bumping the keyboard shortcut for SIGQUIT pretty frequently and losing all my variables from the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are on a *nix platform.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> generates [`SIGQUIT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal), so this isn't really as much about Python.

If you want to disable the key combination you could use [`stty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) before starting Python:

```
stty quit undef
```

Alternatively, use the following to run Python:

```
stty quit undef; python; stty quit ^\\
```

which would disable the key mapping before executing python and set it back later.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  What does the syntax ^\\ mean?

Comment: @wim Essentially mapping `SIGQUIT` to Ctrl+\.  You need to escape the backslash itself.

Answer (score 1):

Answers involving signal handlers do not solve the issue for IPython 5 and higher, because the `Ctrl-\` binding is now handled explicitly at the application level (this had something to do with migration from readline to prompt toolkit).

To disable `Ctrl-\` for newer versions of IPython (tested on IPython 5.3), use the [startup files](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files) to disable that binding:

```
from IPython.terminal.shortcuts import force_exit
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()
ip.pt_cli.application.key_bindings_registry.remove_binding(force_exit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#module-signal) module and set a handler for the `SIGQUIT` signal:

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print("SIGQUIT")

signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, handler)
```

and add this code to IPython [startup files](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files).

Comment: As of IPython 5 this no longer works.  The Ctrl-\ binding is hardcoded.